# Visualising 3D data with a spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, data-visualization

Is there a (possibly spreadsheet?) program that enables manipulation of 3D data? The problem:

- There're several tables (`A, B, C, …`)
- Each table (an `m x n` matrix) represents measured quantities of a system at one point in time
- (Each table describes the same system, just in a different point in time)
- E.g. table `A` = state of the system in time `t=0`, table `B` = state of the system in time `t=1`, …

I'd like to be able to display a 3D spreadsheet containing the evolution of the system in time and scroll between the tables (possibly with the ability of graph-visualization).

To illustrate the situation better:

```
          .
         /|\
          |  time axis
          |

t = 2        +-------+
             |       |
             |   C   |
             |       |
             |       |
t = 1     +-------+  |
          |       |--+
          |   B   |
t = 0  +-------+  |
       |       |  |
       |   A   |  |
       |       |--+
       |       |
       |       |
       +-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since coordinate axes are defined X,(horiz) Z, (depth) , Y (vertical)
- The graph wizard expects you to have names in 1st column and row and then columns X,Y,Z for each data point.
- create this XYZ table using your separate tables which share 2 of the 3 axes.
  When you explictly create this table using links to each table and then copy down the entries you need to fill the missing axis fixed value for each table.
- The result is an automated colour-coded vertical layer for the automated range used.
- here is an example using =RAND() in each cell giving results from 0 to 1.
  [image]

Alternatively if you have N sets of data as a function of X axis (time)
you can use a scatter chart with common X axis for all and secondary axis for values with a wide difference from the rest.

- or use a surface chart if the data is all related but different sensors.
  [image]

[image]

Comment: you must chose only 3 columns of data and create 2 3D charts for 4th dimension

Comment: My problem is, unfortunately, more complicated. To explain my problem on your example: imagine that instead of the Z axis containing only the `x`, `y` and `z` variables, it'd contain **a whole table** – thus making your graph 4D.

Comment: Is it more complicated than my 3rd graph?

Comment: Yes, it is (my problem is that the measured values at one time aren't vectors (like in your 3rd graph), but rather matrices, and linearizing the matrices onto a vector wouldn't make sense), but I'll try to bend your n-3D-graphs approach to my needs.

Comment: Mine are just scalar magnitudes with multiple data sources Z1,Z2 etc so surface would not make sense as your would in Surface chart